# how to change text "Eclipse" to some other text say "AshuEclipse" in the Header left hand corner?

Tags: eclipse, ide-customization

How to change text "Eclipse" to some other text say "AshuEclipse" in the Header left hand corner?

Note: I dont want ot change the header to show workspace ,but I want to change the word Eclipse itself.

Plz suggest.

Answer (score 2):

One solution an one workaround:

---

Solution (in theory, not tested)

The main Eclipse Windows is a `WorkbenchWindow` for the `org.eclipse.ui` plugin. It is created by the platform plugin.
If you look into the resources files within the org.eclipse.platform, you could see some files able to keep this value (for you to change it)

I have found:

`eclipse-3.5.1\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_3.3.201.v200909170800\about.properties`

It contains:

blurb=Eclipse Platform\n\

`eclipse-3.5.1\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_3.3.201.v200909170800\plugin.properties`

With:

```
pluginName=Eclipse Platform
providerName=Eclipse.org

productName=Eclipse Platform
productBlurb=Eclipse Platform\n\
```

Try and modify those values to see if the display can change. (I would bet on `plugin.properties productBlurb`)

Just tested: it does not change the display, so you need to explore some of the jars in the plugins directory of eclipse. In theory, you could change one of its resource file...

---

Workaround (if the previous section does not work)

My eclipse3.5 actually displays the name of the current perspective.

For instance; the Php perspective would be displayed in the header left hand corner:

[alt text http://blog.wampserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/eclipse_perspective_debug.gif](http://blog.wampserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/eclipse_perspective_debug.gif)

So one solution would be to **save your favorite perspective as** "Ashu - Php Debug", and you would get what you want.
(see ["create your own perspective" article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t18187.html))

[alt text http://www.javalobby.org/images/postings/rj/eclipse_perspective/1.gif](http://www.javalobby.org/images/postings/rj/eclipse_perspective/1.gif)

That would need to be redefined for every perspective you are usually using.
And it would still have "Eclipse" at the end...

Comment: I want to change Eclipse itself which is still there in ur ans."-Eclipse" to "-AshuEclipse" not the perspective name . can we do that.

Answer (score 2):

Preferences > General > Workspace > Workspace name

Answer (score 0):

Right click on eclipse shortcut and go to properties.

Change target url text.

```
-> C:\your eclipe folder\eclipse.exe -showlocation <em>YOURTITLE</em>
```

Comment: This does not change the text "Eclipse" but rather adds `YOURTITLE` to the end of the text. What version are you using?

Comment: sorry but I don't know about that. but I think my own is useful :)