# How can I edit eclipse workbench title bar name?

Tags: eclipse, customization, titlebar, workbench

I want to change Host workbench title bar name, from 'Eclipse' to another string.

I changed splash screen by editing 'splash.bmp' in the

plugins\org.eclipse.platform directory.

And, I edited 'plugin.xml' in the same path, but it didn't applied to Host workbench.

(It affects to 'runtime workbench'.)

How can I edit Host workbench title bar? (not Runtime workbench)

Comment: Isn't this similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091727/how-to-change-text-eclipse-to-some-other-text-say-ashueclipse-in-the-header-l?

Comment: Or similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818429/how-to-change-eclipse-window-title

Answer (score 1):

Here's a helpful link:
http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/show-workspace-location-title

We use different releases so I just echo the release name into this configuration file on startup:
/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

If you need help on the method, PM me.

Comment: It's better to summarise the necessary steps in your answer rather than just posting a link, which may not be around forever. Also, StackOverflow has no mechanism for PM's.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Roger.
I also just saw that this post is sort of a duplicate so I won't add more details.