# How to change Eclipse window title?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, window, eclipse-rcp, titlebar

How to change the title (last part of it) of a running Eclipse?

I am speaking about Eclipse distribution itself, not about my program written for Eclipse.

Currently I have the the following title:

[image]

`1` this part is set in `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Workspace name`.

Other parts are autogenerated.

I want to change part `2` which is now `Eclipse`. I have several Eclipses installed and want to refer them here.

**UPDATE**

I found file `plugin.xml` inside `./plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.standard_XXXXX` and found it containing a setting

```
     <property
           name="appName"
           value="Eclipse">
     </property>
```

I changed this as I like but it didn't affect the title.

**UPDATE 2**

Also I found setting in `plugin.properties`

```
productName=Eclipse
```

Unfortunately, changing this also didn't affect the title.

Comment: You probably need to specify the `-clean` option when you restart after editing the files to get Eclipse to pick up the changes.

Comment: is this a e4 application?

Comment: @Ankit this the Eclipse itself, which you can download from Eclipse site.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Unless you are creating your own RCP app

The workbench window title is defined by the branding plugin. Eclipse defines the product and so you will have the "Eclipse" defined in its branding plugin, which will be displayed in the title bar.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer to your question and it might help you or not, but you can have workspace specific title (at the beginning), see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8665249/384674

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me in Eclipse Luna:

1. Open the file `Eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400\plugin.properties` in a text editor. (The exact path will depend on the version.)
2. Change the `productName=Eclipse` value to your desired title. Save the file.
3. Start Eclipse once with the [`-clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030064/how-to-run-eclipse-in-clean-mode-and-what-happens-if-we-do-so) argument.